# Why is the length of an Archimedean spiral so complex?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, arc-length

I was wondering, if you have a simple Archimedean spiral, defined as : $ r=b\times \theta   $ , with the angle $ \theta $ going from $ 0 $ to $ \Theta$

If you consider the spiral as a succession of infintesimally small circle arcs, couldn't you then just get the total length of the spiral by calculating the following integral :

$ \int_{0}^{\Theta}{r(\theta)  \,d\theta} =   \int_{0}^{\Theta}{b \times \theta  \,d\theta} = \frac{1}{2}b \Theta ^2 $

But the Wikipedia page for [Archimedean Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) gives the following formula for the length of the spiral, derived from a cartesian parameterization of the spiral  :
$ {\displaystyle {\frac {b}{2}}\left[\theta \,{\sqrt {1+\theta ^{2}}}+\ln \left(\theta +{\sqrt {1+\theta ^{2}}}\right)\right]} $

Meaning my original formula is evidently false, and I suppose my error lies in considering the spiral as a succession of infintesimally small circle arcs.

Now, I don't really understand why exactly my reasoning is false.

Any help in understanding that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating that formula to see what the integrand ought to be? That could help your understanding.

Comment: Have you looked up the formula for arc length of a line segment in Cartesian, parametric, and/or polar?

Comment: "Now, I don't really understand why exactly my reasoning is false." sure you do. You're treating the spiral as a succession of infintesmal circular arcs, although it is _not_ a succession of circular arcs

Comment: To measure a curve you need to follow it in short segments tangentially. (Your method is like estimating the length of the graph of a function by approximating it with a step function, as you do for finding the area as an integral.)

Answer (score 5):

Treat the spiral as a succession of infinitesimal segments, taking into account that these segments are not perpendicular to the radius, so you should use the Pythagorean theorem (or some other apporach) to find their (infinitesimal) lengths. This way you'll get a more complicated but correct integral.